# How to access the .class of a java class in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to take use of the reflection in clojure.

Suppose there is a part of java code

```java
import com.example.SampleClass;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field field = SampleClass.class.getDeclaredField("someFiledName");
    }
}
```

I can not find how to express the meaning of `SampleClass.class` where there is not any instance of SampleClass. It is just imported so I can not use `(.class SampleClass)` or `(.getClass SampleClass)`

Answer (score 2):

The class itself is the class - only Java, the language, needs `.class`
to get to that.

So you import the class and then you can call your function on it.

```clj
user=> (import 'java.lang.Math) ; that's not really needed
java.lang.Math
user=> (.getDeclaredField java.lang.Math "PI")
#object[java.lang.reflect.Field 0x74ad8d05 "public static final double java.lang.Math.PI"]
```